# C++ typecast overloading

Tags: c++, generics, casting, typecast-operator

Supposed I have a class like this:

```
template<class T>
class Vector2 {
public:
    Vector2(const T a, const T b) : x(a), x(b) {}
    T x;
    T y;
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
const Vector2<double> d(31.4, 48.2);  // note the const!!!

Vector2<int> i = static_cast<Vector2<int>>(d);

// i.x == 31
// i.y == 48
```

I have tried overloading a generic operator but it seems to break when trying to convert from a const value. Help?

Comment: Can't you remove the `static_cast` and just copy `d` to `i` with `Vector2<int> i = d;`? `static_cast` can't cast away `const`-ness, a C-cast or `const_cast` can.

Comment: @cad: Constness is a red herring here. `Vector2<int>` and `Vector2<double>` are two distinct types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide an additional constructor that's taking another template parameter `U`:

```
template<class T>
class Vector2 {
public:
    template <class U>
    Vector2(const Vector2<U> & other) : x(other.x), y(other.y){}

    // other code ommited
};
```

After all, you're trying to use `Vector2<T>::Vector2(const Vector2<U> &)`, where `U = double` and `T = int`.

Note that this has nothing to do with your original vector being `const`. Instead, you're trying to construct a value of type `Vector2<int>` with a value of another type `Value2<double>`. Those are distinct types, and therefore you need to provide a constructor.

Comment: I *suspect* that his problem was that he wrote a casting operator, but did not make a const member function.  As such of course, it wouldn't work on a const variable.

Comment: Is here some way of doing implicit typecasting? It becomes quite tedious to keep calling the copy constructor.

Comment: scratch the above -- it seems the copy ctor is called even when passing a Vector2<double> into a function which takes a Vector2<int> &... interesting!

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be to write a cast operator which does what you want:

```
template<class T>
class Vector2 {
public:
    Vector2(const T a, const T b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    T x;
    T y;

    template<typename U>
    operator Vector2<U>() const { return Vector2<U>( (U)x, (U)y ); }
 // ^^^^^^^^ cast operator
};

int main()
{
    const Vector2<double> d(31.4, 48.2);  // note the const!!!

    Vector2<int> i = static_cast<Vector2<int>>(d);

    return 0;
}
```

An additional constructor as shown in the answer of Zeta is the much more elegant solution.

Comment: a converting constructor is more natural in this case compared to this conversion operator.